# How to view only Mail on shared email account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks, reminder

I have a support account which I should have access to in my Outlook 2010, however, since changing from 2003, the situation has become unusual.

I used to be able to just view shared mail items in a seperate account, without it having the Calendar, Tasks and Reminders popping up in my face all hours of the day.

Now, if I add the account, I get upwards of 60 task reminders that are not my personal account, and that clog up my Reminders window and task list.

Is there a way to show only my Tasks and Reminders in Outlook 2010? I've tried the Advanced Filter option on the Tasks list, but if I set it to show only things from or to myself, everything disappears, or nothing disappears.

I tried looking in the email account settings for something like 'Read email only' or something to do with only showing some of the modules of outlook, but it was useless.

Comment: This sounds like more of an issue with exchange server settings. I would talk to the sysadmin.

Comment: Nothing has changed on the email account (afaik) in a while, but since having to change to 2010b, it's very confusing.